# RubyMine inserting un-editable text

Tags: rubymine

RubyMine has started inserting un-editable text into my Ruby code, and I find it rather annoying. For example, this simple rspec expression:

```
expect(user.name).to be_truthy
```

... becomes this:

```
expect(user.name).to matcher be_truthy
```

Another example, this:

```
Part.first.try(:root_id).nil?
```

... becomes this:

```
Part.first.try( *a :root_id).nil?
```

How can I turn this off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called Parameter Names Hinting. You can disable it in preferences.

You can read more about it here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/2017.1/parameter-names-hinting.html

Comment: Wow, that was painful. Thank you !! :)